# Check wether a value is present in a different list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Relevant (simplified) classes:

```
    public class Host
    {
        public int HostID { get; set; }
        public String HostName { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }

    public class Service
    {
        public int ServiceID { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public int HostID { get; set; }
        public virtual Host Host { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to populate a list of all services given a list of hosts. So for every host in `rsearch.hosts`, I need all the services in `rsearch.hostservices`.

This is what I do now:

```
rsearch.hostservices = db.Services
.Where(j => rsearch.hosts.Select(c => c.HostID).Contains(j.HostID)).ToList();
```

But I always get the following error

```
 System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'xxx.Models.Host'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ids = rsearch.hosts.Select(c => c.HostID).ToList();

rsearch.hostservices = db.Services
.Where(j => ids.Contains(j.HostID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rsearch.hostservices = db.Services
.Where(j => rsearch.hosts.Select(c => c.HostID).ToList().Contains(j.HostID))
.ToList();
```

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation of how it differs from the asker's query and how it addresses the error he is encountering.